# Magento 2 Wishlist siderbar not showing

Tags: magento2, wishlist, magento2-enterprise

I am using `magento 2 EE` and I am facing `wishlist side bar` not showing for `some customers` like:

I have `two customers`

one customer `pawan@gmail.com- customer type - Individual user`

second customer `kumar@gmail.com - customer type - Company admin`

for `Individual user` wishlist sidebar is showing but for `Company admin`  wish list side bar not showing is there any `restriction available` if any one knows please explain i have checked code.

I am not able to find anything!

Comment: Any updates on this? I am facing the same

Comment: @Haritha Magento team released patch I don't have link

Comment: For which version does magento provided patch?

Answer (score 0):

Wishlist sidebar is missing for company user due to the plugin below:
`Magento\Company\Plugin\Wishlist\Block\Customer\SidebarPlugin`, which eliminates the HTML as ('') in the `aroundToHtml`.

```
public function aroundToHtml(Sidebar $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        return $this->companyContext->getCustomerId() &&
               $this->companyManagement->getByCustomerId($this->companyContext->getCustomerId()) ? '' : $proceed();
    }
```